# Forming groups based of integers mod p

Tags: group-theory

In this question, I'm suppose to show whether the following set, accompanied with a binary operation, forms a group or not and justify my answer. I am given:

> All the odd elements of $\mathbb{Z_{64}}$ under multiplication.

I know that the elements of $\mathbb{Z_{64}}$ are given by $$\mathbb{Z_{64}} = {\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2,..., \bar {62}, \bar{63}}.$$

Now considering the odd elements we have $${\bar 3, \bar 5, \bar 7,...,\bar {61}, \bar {63}}$$

Obviously, the identity element is in the set, so that checks out. The associativity property of multiplication should also check out, for example, $$(\bar 2 \cdot \bar3)\bar 4 = \bar2 (\bar 3 \cdot \bar 4)$$ What else am I missing? Am I on the correct path or is this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in general  if $\gcd(a,c)= \gcd(b,c) = 1$, then  $\gcd(ab,c) = 1$, this shows that the odd elements are closed under multiplication and we have by induction if $a$ is odd $\gcd(a,2^n) = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
So if $a$ is odd, we have by Bezout's lemma integers $m,n$ such that $1=ka+64n$, reducing this modulo $64$, we have $\bar 1 \equiv \bar k \bar a \pmod{64}$. Show that $\bar a$ has an inverse. Also note that $k$ must be odd, for else we could multiply the equation $\bar 1 \equiv \bar k \bar a \pmod{64}$ by $32$, obtaining $\bar{32} \equiv \bar 0 \pmod{64}$  which is absurd.

Since you noted that you're not familiar with Bezout's lemma, let me add an alternative proof that does not use it. Note that if $a$ is odd, then $a$ is not a zero divisor modulo $64$, as we have $64 | ab \Rightarrow 64 | b$.
This implies that the function $m_a: \mathbb{Z}/64\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/64\mathbb{Z}, \bar{x} \mapsto \bar{ax}$ is injective for if we have $\bar{ax} \equiv \bar{ay}$, so $ a \cdot ({x-y}) \equiv 0$ now as $a$ is not a zero-divisor, we have $(x-y) \equiv 0$, so $x \equiv y$. Thus $m_a$ is injective as claimed.
Now $\mathbb{Z}/64\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite set, so an injective mapping from $\mathbb{Z}/64\mathbb{Z}$ to itself must be surjective, this implies that there is some $\bar{k} \in \mathbb{Z}/64\mathbb{Z}$, such that $m_a(\bar{k}) = \bar{ak} = 1$, showing that $a$ has a multiplicative inverse. $k$ is odd by the same argument as above.

Comment: Hmmm I have never heard of Bezout's lemma yet. I will look it up and will re-read the proof.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use lemmas/theorems that are not from the textbook itself, although I do like this proof.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 I have added a proof that avoids Bezout's lemma. I hope you know that a function from a finite set to itself is injective iff surjective iff bijective.

Comment: Yes I have learned about injective, surjective and bijective functions. Both proofs are acceptable, but the bottom approach is more *appropriate* in this context. By that I mean using information from my textbook. So it's all clear now.